# Error 404 al consumir web service rest hecho con GX10Ev3 .NET

Tags: genexus, genexusxev3

Hice un webservice REST con Gx10Ev3 .Net
Al llevar la aplicación al cliente e intentar consumirlo obtengo error 404.
Instalé URL Rewrite 2.0.
En el visor de eventos no veo errores.
Agradezco me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Con la poca info que manejamos, tiendo a pensar que algo no quedo bien en el deploy del servicio, seguramente en la etapa de "llevar la app al cliente". Podes consumirlo usando una herramienta externa, como Postman, por ejemplo? Revisaria que efectivamente ese servicio haya quedo en algun endpoint publico y accesible.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás te falte realizar el registro de las extensiones SVC, esto se hace mediante el comando:

```
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" –i
```

Adicionalmente, debes revisar en Activar o Desactivar características de Windows que tengas checkeado con Framework 3.5.1:

- Activación HTTP de Windows Communication Foundation.
- Activación no HTTP de Windows Communication Foundation.

Y en Framework 4.5 advanced Services > WCFServices:

- Activación HTTP

Puedes leer los algunos errores más comunes en:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18398,URLRewrite+-+Common+issues

Como también probar si están fucionando los servicios REST con el siguiente .xpz:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18365,REST+Web+Services+Installation+Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por las respuestas. Efectivamente faltaba agregar alguna de las características mencionadas. No se específicamente cual porque agregué de todo al mismo tiempo